# Does rooting an android phone effectively also unlock it from network

Tags: rooting, mobile-network, sim-unlocking

If you root an android phone does this also unlock it from a network?

I.e. say you had a moto g locked to the vodafone network, and then you rooted the phone, would it then be unlocked from vodafone?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. Rooting gives you access, unlocking allows you to use a phone with other networks.

http://www.howtogeek.com/135663/htg-explains-whats-the-difference-between-jailbreaking-rooting-and-unlocking/